# How to resolve the apostrophe inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php

How to use correctly the ' inside this javascript.

i try this different solutions but it does not work

```
     $introduction = 'Hello, it\'s chrismas'.
     $introduction = str_replace('&#039;', '', $introduction);
     $introduction = json_encode($introduction);
     $introduction = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($introduction, ENT_QUOTE);
```

There the complete code.

```
     if (MODULE_WEB_PUSH_SPECIAL == 'True') {
        $special_products = $this->getSpecialsProducts();

        if (!empty($special_products) && $_SESSION['SpecialsProducts'] === false) {
          $message_products_special = $special_products;
          $_SESSION['SpecialsProducts'] = true;

          $special_link = CLICSHOPPING::link(null, 'Products&Specials');

          $output .= '
<script>
Push.create(\'' . $introduction . '\', {
    body: \'' . $message_products_special . '\',
    icon: \'sources/images/logos/others/favicon.png\',
    timeout: 8000,               // Timeout before notification closes automatically.
    vibrate: [100, 100, 100],    // An array of vibration pulses for mobile devices.
    onClick: function() {
        window.location = "' . $special_link . '";
    }  
});
</script>
  ';
        }
      }
```

Comment: You should use `json_encode()`

Comment: Did you even test this code? Quotes are missing on line 1, closing parentheses are missing on line 3, closing single quote is missing on last line, I can go on.

Comment: @DerekPollard, does'nt work,  Update for the code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only thing you need to use is [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). This will deal with all possible escaping issues that might arise. The resulting value will be quoted already, there's no need to use quotes in the JavaScript code.

When you're working with long blocks of text, using a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) makes things much easier to read, and I would recommend putting your PHP values into variables to ensure they're more separate from your JavaScript code.

```
$introduction = "Hello, it's Christmas";
if (MODULE_WEB_PUSH_SPECIAL == 'True') {
    $special_products = $this->getSpecialsProducts();

    if (!empty($special_products) && $_SESSION['SpecialsProducts'] === false) {
        $message_products_special = $special_products;
        $_SESSION['SpecialsProducts'] = true;

        $special_link = CLICSHOPPING::link(null, 'Products&Specials');

        $introduction = json_encode($introduction);
        $message_products_special = json_encode($message_products_special);
        $special_link = json_encode($special_link);

        $output = <<< JS
<script>
/* Begin PHP values */
var introduction = $introduction;
var message_products_special = $message_products_special;
var special_link = $special_link;
/* End PHP values */

Push.create(introduction, {
    body: message_products_special,
    icon: 'sources/images/logos/others/favicon.png',
    timeout: 8000,               // Timeout before notification closes automatically.
    vibrate: [100, 100, 100],    // An array of vibration pulses for mobile devices.
    onClick: function() {
        window.location = special_link;
    }  
});
</script>
JS;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Escaping quotes in javascript.
Using double qoutes allows you to have a single quote inside the double quote.
    "'"
Using backslash prevents the next special character. Ie
    '\'';
```

In your script your combining javascript and php in the wrong way. You need to echo php variables, other wise php will not parse the assuring. To do that, I am using the php shorthand  which is equivalent to

```
<?php $introduction = 'Hello, it\'s chrismas'.
     $introduction = str_replace('&#039;', '', $introduction);
     $introduction = json_encode($introduction);
     $introduction = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($introduction, ENT_QUOTE); ?>



  <script>
  Push.create('<?=$introduction?>', {
      body: '<?=$message?>',
      icon: 'images/logos/others/favicon.png',
      timeout: 8000,               // Timeout before notification closes automatically.
      vibrate: [100, 100, 100],    // An array of vibration pulses for mobile devices.
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: I no choice to use $output, it's a simple example, but I have more. I put above all the code.

Answer (score 0):

This can all be avoided by using double quotes (`" ... "`) for `$output`.

Specifically, `$output .= "` ... `";`

Comment: Edwin Dijas Chiwona has given a better answer